# Google translate repsonse text garbled

Tags: node.js, google-translate

I'm building a small commandline utility to help me do some translations in nodejs. The problem is that the response text I get from Google is garbled. The best I can tell, nodejs is sending a properly encoded request, but it obviously isn't. If I use the ANSI charset everything works as expected. The main idea is not to have the string right there in the source of course, I'm having it like this as I'm trying to figure things out. The source is encoded as UTF8 while the data I'm parsing through to get to the strings in question is in UTF16 LE format, but I don't think that's important for this example.

```
const https = require('https');

let uri = 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ru&tl=en&dt=t&q=Приобрести контейнеры с амуницией';

console.log(uri);
console.log(encodeURI(uri));
console.log(decodeURI(encodeURI(uri)));

https.get(encodeURI(uri), (res) =>
{
    const { statusCode } = res;
    let error;

    if (statusCode !== 200)
    {
        error = new Error('Request Failed: ' + statusCode);
    }

    if (error)
    {
        console.log(error.message);
        res.resume();
        return;
    }

    let data = '';

    res.on('data', (chunk) =>
    {
        console.log('chunks:', chunk);
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () =>
    {
        let parsed;

        try {
            parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('parsing error', e);
        }

        console.log(data.length, data);
        console.log(parsed[0][0][0]);
    });
}).on('error', (e) =>
{
    console.error(e);
});
```

This is the output I get in the commandline.

1. the original uri
2. the encoded uri
3. the decoded encoded uri
4. the data response dump
5. size of the response string and the string
6. json decoded string

I'm assuming nodejs is sending a garbled request to google, but I don't understand how to fix that.

```
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ru&tl=en&dt=t&q=Приобрести контейнеры с амуницией
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ru&tl=en&dt=t&q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D1%81%20%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ru&tl=en&dt=t&q=Приобрести контейнеры с амуницией
chunks: <Buffer 5b 5b 5b 22 d0 a0 d1 9f d0 a1 d0 82 d0 a0 d1 91 d0 a0 d1 95 d0 a0 20 c2 b1 20 d0 a1 d0 82 d0 a0 c2 b5 d0 a1 d0 83 d0 a1 2c 20 d0 a0 d0 81 d0 a0 d1 94 ... >
165 '[[["РџСЂРёРѕР ± СЂРµСЃС, РЁРєРѕРЅС‚РµР№РЅРµСЂС ‹СЃ Р ° РјСѓРЅРЁС † РёРµР№","РџСЂРёРѕР±СЂРµСЃС‚Рё РєРѕРЅС‚РµР№РЅРµСЂС‹ СЃ Р°РјСѓРЅРёС†РёРµР№",null,null,3]],null,"ru"]'
РџСЂРёРѕР ± СЂРµСЃС, РЁРєРѕРЅС‚РµР№РЅРµСЂС ‹СЃ Р ° РјСѓРЅРЁС † РёРµР№
```

If I load the request uri in the browser, I get expected results.

```
[[["Purchase containers with ammunition","Приобрести контейнеры с амуницией",null,null,3]],null,"ru"]
```

Comment: Why not trying the [NodeJS client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) instead of doing the http request?

Comment: @F10 I wasn't aware that existed. I did find some Google Translate stuff on npm but it was old and deprecated. I figured Google didn't want their stuff to be used for without a quota and someone suggested this URL as something their translation Chrome addon used, so I went with that. Oh, nvm I now see it does have a quota. Or at least it requires a project id.

Answer (score 0):

OK, new day comes with new ideas. I figured this morning some headers may be missing and it turned out my request needed a valid user agent to be provided, but only for these UTF requests. Go figure. Various header combinations garbled the response even more so it took some guessing to get there.

```
let headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0'
};

https.get(uri, { headers: headers }, (res) =>
{
    ...
})
```